# Missed software drivers during 18.04' s installation

Tags: drivers

I just bought HP elitebook 840 G5 and I completed install Ubuntu 18.04 .
But I don't know how to activate the fingerprint and I can't find the appearance in the settings.
And some of the keyboard key are not working.
Any way to help would be appreciated and suggestions

Comment: Why are you installing a version of Ubuntu that is post standard support? I’d strongly recommend 22.04LTS (or 20.04LTS) - and unfortunately 18.04 isn’t covered by this site as it’s past its support time.

Comment: Start over and install a newer release. 18.04 is over 5 years old and community support ends in just a few days. If this is a new installation, install 22.04.

Comment: Short and painless install Ubuntu release 22.04. 18.04 reach soon EOL.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS is the 2018-April release (*Ubuntu uses the year.month format!*) which had 5 years of *standard* supported life. You can confirm this on your installation using `ubuntu-support-status`, with those five years of standard supported life scheduled to end 30-April-2023. Life was extended for architectures by Canonical for 1 month, thus EOSS is now 31-May-2023; why waste time setting up a system in its last hours/days (*you didn't mention architecture; your system may already be EOL too or have mere days left!*)